# Can the fuzzy rules in a function block have as antecedents the outputs of another function block?

Tags: jfuzzylogic

I want to implement a cascade of Fuzzy Inference Systems (FIS) in jFuzzyLogic. More specifically, I want to turn the output variables of a FIS into input of another. Could be the fuzzy rules in a function block have as antecedents the outputs of another function block? How do they have to be declared?